# Envio de datos en app Android

Tags: android

Tengo el siguiente método

```
private void valida_webView() {
    lk="url-serv";
    final WebView myBrowser;
    myBrowser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    final MyJavaScriptInterface myJavaScriptInterface = new MyJavaScriptInterface(this);
    myBrowser.addJavascriptInterface(myJavaScriptInterface, "AndroidFunction");
    myBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    myBrowser.loadUrl("url-server");

    Msg = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.msg);
    btnSendMsg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sendmsg);
    btnSendMsg.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String msgToSend = Msg.getText().toString();
            myBrowser.loadUrl("javascript:callFromActivity(\"" + msgToSend + "\")");
        }
    });
}
```

En este método lo que deseo es enviar solo la letra 'x' a un servidor. Actualmente tengo definido un campo de texto y que haga el envío de lo que está en el interior del campo de texto, todo esto programado en el evento `onClick` del botón, pero lo que deseo realizar es que automáticamente al cargar el sistema me haga el envío de la letra 'x' al servidor, quitando el campo de texto y el botón. Este método es llamado en `onCreate`.

La función javascript callFromActivity es la siguientes:

```
<p id="mytext">texto por defecto</p>
<script language="javascript">
function callFromActivity(msg){

document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML = msg;
if(msg != "x"){ document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML = "no hay x";}
else
{
document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML = "hay x";}
 }

</script>
```

Principalmente lo que necesito es que al recibir la "x" se ejecute otra acción en el servidor. El envío de este dato "x" tiene que ser automático al cargar la aplicación en android, las pruebas que realizo al crear un campo de texto con un botón me funcionan correctamente, pero no he podido dejar que la función envíe automáticamente y sin la intervención del usuario dicho dato.

Saludos.

Amigos ya resolví mi problema, les dejos los siguientes códigos.

```
private void valida_version() {

    final WebView myBrowser;
    myBrowser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    myBrowser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    myBrowser.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
      myBrowser.loadUrl("url-server.php");

    myBrowser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            String msgToSend = "x";
            myBrowser.loadUrl("javascript:callFromActivity(\"" + msgToSend + "\")");
        }
    });
}
```

y este es el código del lado del servidor.

```
<div id="webv"></div>
<div id="box_update_app"></div>
<p id="mytext"></p>


<script type="text/javascript">
 function callFromActivity(msg){

 document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML = 'Mensaje: '+msg;

 if(msg != "x"){ 
  document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML = "no hay x";
  }else{
  document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML = "hay x";
   }
 }
 </script>
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda y orientación.

Saludos.

Comment: No parece javascript. ¿están bien los tags?

Comment: Estimado, edité los tags

Comment: Rodrigo el titulo sigue diciendo javascript. el Lenguaje es java.

Comment: estimado, he realizado nuevamente los cambios.

Comment: @Rodrigo agrega tu método callFromActivity

Answer (score 2):

Lo importante aquí es revisar que es lo que realiza el método `callFromActivity()` de la interfaz Javascript, al parecer, lo que deseas es cargar la url con un parámetro en el querystring, no veo la necesidad de usar una interfaz, de hecho en algunas API se marco como obsoleto este método por cuestiones de seguridad, para evitar inyección de code.

puede realizarlo de esta forma:

```
String msgToSend = Msg.getText().toString();
String myUrl ="http://stackoverflow.com";
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(myUrl + "?" + msgToSend));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Si lo deseas realizar con la interfaz simplemente asegura que tu función Javascript `callFromActivity()`  reciba correctamente el valor de `msgToSend` y cargue ese valor en la url.

Comment: muchas gracias por su respuesta y disculpa por mi tardanza, he modificado mi pregunta indicando aún más detalles.

Comment: Buen día Rodrigo, con tu actualización, acabo de ver tu funcion callFromActivity() pero lo que estarías realizando es configurar un texto a un elemento, en este caso <p id="mytext">texto por defecto</p> pero no estarías enviando el texto a un servidor. Quieres enviar el dato a una página externa o quieres ver un cambio de este dato en tu aplicación dentro del html???

Comment: Muchas gracias @Elenasys, lo que deseo es enviar el dato a una página externa, y el dato recibido por la página externa será utilizado para una decisión, por eso en este caso se definió simplemente con la letra "x" 

if(msg != "x"){ document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML = "no hay x";}
else
{
document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML = "hay x";}
 }