# ¿Por qué Java permite el uso de "final" dentro de métodos y funciones?

Tags: java

Miraba una de las [preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/9899/) y me surgió la duda que dice el titulo.

¿Por qué es permitida la palabra clave `final` dentro de métodos y funciones?

Comment: No hay "funciones" en Java, sólo métodos. Quizá quisiste decir "métodos y variables"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La palabra `final` aplicada a variables significa que **el valor** de la variable no puede ser modificado. Esto permite al compilador asegurar que la variable solo es inicializada en su declaración (en el caso de atributos de clase, la variable debe ser asignada al declararse o en el constructor de la clase). En caso que la variable sea reinicializada, esto lanzará un error de compilación.

Para variables de tipo primitivo, esto es simple de comprender:

```
final int i = 5;
i = 7; //error de compilación aquí
```

Para variables de tipo de objeto, hay que considerar que el valor de la variable es una referencia y no su estado. Aquí un ejemplo:

```
public class MiEntidad {
    int id;
    String nombre;
}

//asignando una referencia como valor a la variable
final MiEntidad miEntidad = new MiEntidad();
//aquí se modifica el estado interno de dicha referencia
//pero la referencia mantiene su mismo valor
miEntidad.id = 1; //esto cambia el estado de l
miEntidad.nombre = "Luiggi";
//aquí se intenta asignar una nueva referencia a la variable
//por ende, ocurre un error de compilación
miEntidad = new MiEntidad();
```

Puesto que una variable se declara como `final`, esto asegura al compilador que la variable no pueda cambiar su valor. Esto es muy útil cuando se tienen variables locales a un método y estas necesitan utilizarse dentro de una clase local al método (comúnmente llamado clases anónimas) puesto que esta clase no puede asignar valores a variables que no pertenecen a la clase ni a variables locales. Aquí un ejemplo:

```
public void metodoX() {
    //si remueves la palabra final, saldrá un error de compilación
    //en la clase interna
    final int tope = 10;
    Thread t = new Thread( () -> {
        //esta es una clase interna local al método metodoX
        //que implementa la interfaz Runnable
        //y hace uso de la variable externa "tope"
        //puesto que "tope" es ajena a la clase interna y
        //no pertenece a la clase donde se encuentra metodoX
        //la variable necesita ser declarada como final
        for (int i = 1; i <= tope; i++) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Hola %d", i));
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

---

`final` tiene otros usos:

- Declarar una clase como `final`. Esto hace que la clase no pueda ser extendida. Ejemplo:

  ```
  public final class NoMeHereden {
  }

  //error de compilación
  //puesto que la clase NoMeHereden está declarada como final
  public class YoQuieroHeredarDe extends NoMeHereden {
  }
  ```
- Declarar un método como `final`: El método no puede ser sobre escrito (overridden). Ejemplo:

  ```
  public class HeredenDeMi {
      public final void peroNoSobreescribanEsto() {
      }
  }

  public class YoHeredoDe extends HeredenDeMi {
      //error de compilación
      //el método está declarado como final
      //no puede ser sobreescrito
      @Override
      public void peroNoSobreescribanEsto() {
      }
  }
  ```
- Definir un atributo de clase como `static final`: El atributo posee un **valor** constante en tiempo de compilación y ejecución. Esto se utiliza principalmente para definir variables constantes a nivel de aplicación. Ejemplo:

  ```
  public class MisConstantes {
      public static final int CERO = 0;
      public static final String DELIMITADOR_BASE = "_";
      //como es una constante, se debe asegurar que la variable
      //y su estado no puedan ser modificados en tiempo de
      //compilación
      public static final List<String> EXTENSIONES_ACEPTADAS =
          Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("txt", "pdf", "csv"));
  }
  ```

Adicional: los atributos definidos en una interfaz **siempre** son declarados como `static final`, es decir, son constantes.

Más información oficial (de la especificación del lenguaje Java) al respecto:

- [Variables finales](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)
- [Clases finales](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1.2)
- [Atributos finales](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.2)
- [Métodos finales](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.3)

Comment: Entonces, dentro de métodos y funciones actúa de igual manera, no? Me refiero a que se define la variable local con un valor y este no puede ser cambiado, algo así como un `readonly` en C#?

Comment: Correcto, es similar a `readonly` de C#. En Java, `final` tiene más funcionalidades.

Comment: Entonces, ¿`final` no es solo `sealed` en C#?

Comment: No, no lo es. Su comportamiento es ligeramente distinto. Depende si lo utilizas en una variable, en un método o en una clase

Comment: Podría ser útil incluir la(s) referencias(s) a la [*Java Language Specification*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html) donde se *especifica* el uso de `final`.

Comment: @PaulVargas están al final de la respuesta ;)

Answer (score 3):

`final` tiene varios usos, dentro de los métodos no solo es importante para indicar que la variable no puede ser modificada... como ya explico @LuiggiMendoza, también es **obligatoria** cuando quieres usar una de estas variables en una clase anónima..

ej:

```
int variable = 3;

Thread t = new Thread() { // clase anonima
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(variable); // <-- error de compilacion
    }
};   
t.start();
```

Ahora si pones el modificador final sobre

```
final int variable = 3;

Thread t = new Thread() { // clase anonima
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(variable); // OK
    }
};   
t.start();
```